# My project cannot find google-services.json in build variant folders

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have 3 different build variants:

[image]

I have put different google-services.json in each build variants folder:

[image]

**app gradle**

```
// at bottom
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Error**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDevConfigDebugGoogleServices'.
>
>   > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.     Searched Location:
>   >     .../app/google-services.json

It does not even try to find in build variant folder.

What could be wrong?

Comment: did you try to create debug and release inside each flavor, for example DevConfig/debug/google-service.json?

Comment: the easy way is moving google-services.json to app/google-services.json, if you look into the file already defined all packages.

Comment: I use different google-services.json for different build variant, and I don't need to separate into debug and release, but I will try it @CôngHải

Comment: I know you have many build flavors, it already defined inside each google-services.json you download from firebase, so you only need put in app/google-serives.json is ok

Comment: If so, then AS will pick up the one in app, not depend on which product flavor I use to build with.

Comment: @CôngHải it doesn't work if I add debug and release folders too

Answer (score 2):

It is an existing bug(?) in Google as posted [here](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/91) when using google-services v4.3.3 requires the product flavours name to be all lowercased.